# Rounding issue using PHP

Tags: php, mysql

Trying to overlay entries onto a PDF, however I'm having trouble on the extraction. The value of the entry is 2.914, but when I pull it through using

```
$dyed_ppg = $form_data['field']['12']);
```

It spits out 2.92 and rounded the number up. I've tried using

```
$dyed_ppg = number_format((float)$form_data['field']['12'], 4, '.', '');
```

But it outputs it as 2.9200

In SQL it is 2.914 so I'm not sure where the rounding is occuring...

Comment: how do you fetch the data?

Comment: where you rounding? and what is your expected output?

Comment: It's the type of field?

Comment: Is the value saved as a string, a float, or a double in the database?

Comment: @sgt Data fetching occurs as using '            $form_data = GFPDFEntryDetail::lead_detail_grid_array($form, $lead);'

Comment: @worldofjr Its actually saved as a varchar

Comment: which version it is?